# How to compare data in 2 columns in Excel and then in one cell, determine if there are similar data in both columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns in Excel: the first contains a list of employee names who perform function A, and the second contains a list of employee names who perform function B.

What I want is to identify, in one cell, if there is one employee whose name appears in both the first and second columns. It does not have to show which name(s) appears in both columns, it just needs to identify IF there are any names that appear in both columns.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Can you show some example?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say column A is the list of employees doing function 1, and column B is the function 2 list.

Put this in the first position of column C and copy down the list:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$999,0)),"","Match")
```

Any entries that are in column A that have a match in column B will show "Match".  Modify `$B$999` to match the length of your column.

Then it is just a case of scanning the column C to see if there are any matches.

Comment: To make this a bit more efficient, this data can be put into a list (ctrl + a, ctrl + l), then use the filter options for column C to list only matches.

Answer (score 1):

For a single-cell solution, assuming data in rows 2 to 100 (adjust as required) try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A100,B2:B100))>0
```

returns TRUE if there are any matches, otherwise FALSE.